# Where is the 'unit'-ratio convenience typedef?

Tags: c++, numeric, std

[`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) provides convenience typedefs for metric prefixes (centi, deci, deca, hecto).

```
yocto   std::ratio<1, 1000000000000000000000000>, if std::intmax_t can represent the denominator
zepto   std::ratio<1, 1000000000000000000000>, if std::intmax_t can represent the denominator
atto    std::ratio<1, 1000000000000000000>
femto   std::ratio<1, 1000000000000000>
pico    std::ratio<1, 1000000000000>
nano    std::ratio<1, 1000000000>
micro   std::ratio<1, 1000000>
milli   std::ratio<1, 1000>
centi   std::ratio<1, 100>
deci    std::ratio<1, 10>
deca    std::ratio<10, 1>
hecto   std::ratio<100, 1>
kilo    std::ratio<1000, 1>
mega    std::ratio<1000000, 1>
giga    std::ratio<1000000000, 1>
tera    std::ratio<1000000000000, 1>
peta    std::ratio<1000000000000000, 1>
exa     std::ratio<1000000000000000000, 1>
zetta   std::ratio<1000000000000000000000, 1>, if std::intmax_t can represent the numerator
yotta   std::ratio<1000000000000000000000000, 1>, if std::intmax_t can represent the numerator
```

What's missing? Well... the unit ratio `std::ratio<1,1>`.
I am aware that there is no official metric prefix name for the unit, but that does not mean that it does not exist.
Nowhere in [[ratio.si]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ratio#si), the unit prefix is mentioned. So I wonder: what would be the *most paradigmatic* way to work with a 'unit' ratio? For example, when `duration_cast`-ing to whole seconds.

Comment: what you listed is only some aliases. Nobody will prevent you from either using `std::ratio<1,1>` or give it some name

Comment: sorry, to me it is completely unclear what problem you are trying to solve. Can you show some code as example where you would use a `unit_ratio` ?

Comment: i mean either you are doing something generic, then you use `std::ration<m,n>` or not generic then you use eg `yocto` but scaling with `std::ratio<1,1>` is like not scaling

Comment: @idclev463035818 `std::duration<float, std::ratio<1,1>>` vs `std::duration<float, std::milli>`. Why use  `std::milli` if I can't use it for the unit case anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, `std::duration` has a default for the second parameter, which is `std::ratio<1,1>`. "Why use std::milli if I can't use it for the unit case anyway" because `std::milli` is not the same as `std::ratio<1,1>`. What do you mean with "I can't use it" ?

Comment: `when duration_cast-ing to whole seconds.` do: `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>`. There's no prefix for `one` in [si prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), I am fine with `std::ratio<1>`. I believe the answer would be opinion based - everyone understands "most paradigmatic" in different way.

Comment: Why use `std::milli` if I can write `std::ratio<1, 1000>`? Because it's convenient.
Why use `std::ratio<1,1>`? Because there is no convenience typedef. 
Why do we have a '1' in multiplication and a '0' in addition if they are equivalent to 'not multiplying' and 'not adding' anyway? Because it is consistent.

Comment: because you can also add a 1 and you can multiply by 0. Adding two `std::ratio`s on the other hand  is not defined

Comment: Why do you want to convert from seconds to seconds? Because you can?

Comment: as I wrote above, the only instance when you want to multiply by 1 is when you actually multiply by `x` (and `x` can be `1`). But in that case it is not relevant whether there is a named constant `const int ONE = 1;`. On the other hand, why would you write `y = ONE * z;` ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik , I convert from anything else to seconds.

Comment: but anything to seconds is not 1:1

Comment: it would really help if you could show code that needs a name for `std::ratio<1,1>`. I still think that you can't. I'll be happy to get convinced to be wrong

Comment: No, that's why I want to make explicit that I cast from, say, `std::milli` to `std::unit`.

Comment: Please show an actual example where you convert anything else to seconds with `std::ratio<1, 1>`. Somehow I think you have a misunderstanding of this concept.

Comment: `auto t = std::chrono::milliseconds { 100 }; auto fp = std::duration_cast<std::duration<float, std::ratio<1,1>>(t);`
I know that `ratio<1,1>` is the default template parameter, but what if, in another case, it is not?

Comment: Please show this _"another case"_.

Comment: `template<typename Period=std::milli> something {};`

Comment: Now you have to provide it because you wrote a very special function template. The standard only provides function templates with this default so it's not necessary to have `std::ratio<1, 1>`. The standard solved the problem for its templates. If some users do unusual things these users have to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what would be the most paradigmatic way to work with a 'unit' ratio?

The most pragmatic way to work with a unit ratio is to not use it.

It's a bit like asking what is the best way to multiply by `1`. You don't.

> For example, when duration_cast-ing to whole seconds.

You would write `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>`.

`std::ratio<1,1>` has no name because you never need a name for it. For example `std::duration` has already a default period of `std::ratio<1,1>`.

If you still want to give it a name you can do so:

```
using unit_ratio = std::ratio<1>;
```

Comment: Geek trivia:  An early draft of the proposal that put `ratio` into C++11 actually did have a type alias for `ratio<1>`.  I don't remember what we called it.  We pulled it out early due to the lack of a metric name for it.